# BeautifulSoup: Remove empty div tag

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am extracting data from a website and this is how I am extracting data from `div`.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_mining")
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')

flags = re.DOTALL
ptag = re.compile(r'<[^>]*?>', flags)
pdiv = re.compile('<div [^>]*?>(.*?)</div>', flags)

def remove(soup, tagname):
    for tag in soup.findAll(tagname):
        contents = tag.contents
        parent = tag.parent
        tag.extract()
        for tag in contents:
            parent.append(tag)

def main():
    divs = pdiv.findall(soup.prettify())
    remove(soup, "script")
    for i, d in enumerate(divs):
        parts = [s.strip() for s in ptag.split(d)]
        text = '\n'.join(s for s in parts if s)
        print("%d:\n%s\n" % (i, text))
```

OUTPUT:

```
0:


1:


2:


3:


4:
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

5:


6:


7:
```

How to remove empty `div`?

**UPDATE**: Added URL of the webpage. Updated the OUTPUT based upon the webpage

Comment: I would recommend extracting empty `<div>` tags with BeautifulSoup, not with regexp. Parsing HTML with regexp is most often not good idea. Can you provide sample input/url?